# creating json output using php

Tags: php, json

I have this so far :

```
if (is_request_var('requestor') == 'PPA'){
   $dataJson[][]  = array("status" => "success","value" => $fetchValue ,"postcode" => $fetchPostCode,"params"=>""); 

   $notice = $dataJson;
}
```

I want to get (refer below) from PHP how do i arrange my PHP array code

```
jQuery191013316784294951245_1485527378760([
  {
    "value": "\u003cstrong\u003eNAIROBI\u003c/strong\u003e KENYATTA AVENUE, GENERAL POST OFFICE, 00100",
    "postcode": "00100"
  },
  {
    "value": "\u003cstrong\u003eNAIROBI\u003c/strong\u003e HAILE SALASSIE AVENUE, CITY SQUARE, QLD, 00200",
    "postcode": "00200"
  }
])
```

Comment: You should use json_encode function: json_encode(array("status" =>..... and return it.

Comment: @rescobar would it return the way i want my json data formatted ?

Comment: @ Philip W Mars , It will return the JSON representation of a value, in this case of an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$dataJson = array("value" => $fetchValue, "postcode" => $fetchPostCode);
$notice = json_encode($dataJson);
echo $notice;
```

Returns a string containing the JSON representation of value.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php